# How to get the first result from async tasks which is not None

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a situation where I need to stop the tasks in the async function where it matches the condition whether in `task_1` or `task_2` or `task_3` and also check that result is not `None` if the results is `None` then I'd like to proceed till the function gets the first result which is not `None`. Here is the minimal reproducible code I have so far:

```
import asyncio


async def task_1(_id):
    _ids = ["230327-12717", "230221-28276", "230214-06090"]

    for i in _ids:
        if i == _id:
            return f"Found {_id} in task_1"


async def task_2(_id):
    _ids = ["230502-14191", "230425-17005", "230327-14434"]

    for i in _ids:
        if i == _id:
            return f"Found {_id} in task_2"


async def task_3(_id):
    _ids = ["230404-23786", "230221-25729", "230221-28276"]

    for i in _ids:
        if i == _id:
            return f"Found {_id} in task_3"


async def main(_id):
    tasks = [task_1(_id), task_2(_id), task_3(_id)]

    finished, unfinished = await asyncio.wait(
        tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED
    )

    print(finished)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main("230502-14191"))
```

which gives output:

```
{<Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<task_2() done, defined at /home/zerox/pipedrive_CRM/minimal.py:13> result='Found 230502-14191 in task_2'>, <Task finished name='Task-3' coro=<task_3() done, defined at /home/zerox/pipedrive_CRM/minimal.py:21> result=None>, <Task finished name='Task-4' coro=<task_1() done, defined at /home/zerox/pipedrive_CRM/minimal.py:5> result=None>}
```

And my expected output should be something like this:

```
{<Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<task_2() done, defined at /home/zerox/pipedrive_CRM/minimal.py:13> result='Found 230502-14191 in task_2'>}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `finished` is a set. Just pop the first element.

Comment: Actually I am looking for to stop the function when first result found which isn't `None`. I don't want look up the `_id` in other tasks if it is found in any one task. For example: if `_id` found in `task_2` I don't want to look up in the `task_3` I just want to return.

Comment: Then your code is completely correct. However, in this particular example, all three functions finish at the exact same time so there isn't a "first" result to stop at. If you add `await asyncio.sleep` of varying lengths to your functions you'll see that the intended behavior is there.

Comment: @SimonUnderwood Sorry, but almost everything you said is wrong. When dealing with a set, there is no "first" element because sets are by definition unordered, so all you can do is pop _some_ element. Also, the tasks decidedly do **not** finish at the _"exact same time"_ because they do not run in parallel, only one of them ever executes at a time because the event loop runs in a single thread. So yes, one of them will definitely finish first.

Comment: The problem here is that neither of your tasks _ever_ yields control back to the event loop (i.e. there is no `await` in them). This means that there will be no context switch between them, which effectively results in them being called sequentially (one after the other).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info), so I'll try and interpret what you actually want to accomplish.

Whenever you are dealing with multiple tasks that need to be coordinated in *some way*, it is a good idea to start with the available [synchronization primitives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html).

In this case, you want the search for your specific ID to *stop in all tasks*, as soon as possible, after it has been found in one of them.

An [`Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#event) object can be very useful for such a situation. The main coroutine schedules the "searching" tasks and then simply **waits** for the event to be set. The tasks all carry a reference to that event object and once the ID is found by one of the tasks, it sets the event. The main coroutine then simple cancels all the tasks and cleans up.

Demo:

```py
from asyncio import Event, create_task, gather, run, sleep
from collections.abc import Iterable


async def _search(id_: str, ids: Iterable[str], found: Event, name: str) -> None:
    for i in ids:
        await sleep(0)
        print(f"{name} checking {i}")
        if i == id_:
            print(f"Found {id_} in {name}")
            found.set()


async def task_1(id_: str, found: Event) -> None:
    ids = ["230327-12717", "230221-28276", "230214-06090"]
    await _search(id_, ids, found, "task_1")


async def task_2(id_: str, found: Event) -> None:
    ids = ["230502-14191", "230425-17005", "230327-14434"]
    await _search(id_, ids, found, "task_2")


async def task_3(id_: str, found: Event) -> None:
    ids = ["230404-23786", "230221-25729", "230221-28276"]
    await _search(id_, ids, found, "task_3")


async def main(id_: str) -> None:
    found = Event()
    tasks = [
        create_task(task_1(id_, found)),
        create_task(task_2(id_, found)),
        create_task(task_3(id_, found)),
    ]
    await found.wait()
    for task in tasks:
        task.cancel()
    await gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(main("230502-14191"))
```

Output:

```
task_1 checking 230327-12717
task_2 checking 230502-14191
Found 230502-14191 in task_2
task_3 checking 230404-23786
task_1 checking 230221-28276
```

A few things to note:

- Some `await` within the `for`-loop is necessary for this simple example to ensure that a context switch can happen. Otherwise the tasks will simply execute sequentially. That is why I added the `await asyncio.sleep(0)`.
- As you can see, even though the ID was found by task 2, both task 1 and task 3 each still had one more go. There is no way to prevent that because the event loop decides itself, which coroutine to switch to at any given moment. And `await found.wait()` in our `main` coroutine only guarantees that it will block until the event is set, not that it receives control right away. But you'll notice that none of the tasks actually finished, i.e. none of them went though all their IDs because they were cancelled before they could.
- I am using [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) with `return_exceptions=True` because I do not want any of the `CancelledError`s to propagate up to the `main` coroutine.
- Technically you don't need the `gather` at all because the coroutines will be cancelled regardless, but it is bad form to leave dangling un-`await`-ed tasks lying around. You should **always** `await` your tasks at *some* point. And `gather` seems like the easiest solution here.

---

### PS: Returning results from `asyncio.gather`

If you want the `task_` functions to return something, `gather` will collect those results for you too:

```py
from asyncio import Event, create_task, gather, run, sleep
from collections.abc import Iterable


async def _search(id_: str, ids: Iterable[str], found: Event, name: str) -> str:
    for i in ids:
        await sleep(0)
        print(f"{name} checking {i}")
        if i == id_:
            found.set()
            return f"Found {id_} in {name}"


async def task_1(id_: str, found: Event) -> str:
    ids = ["230327-12717", "230221-28276", "230214-06090"]
    return await _search(id_, ids, found, "task_1")


async def task_2(id_: str, found: Event) -> str:
    ids = ["230502-14191", "230425-17005", "230327-14434"]
    return await _search(id_, ids, found, "task_2")


async def task_3(id_: str, found: Event) -> str:
    ids = ["230404-23786", "230221-25729", "230221-28276"]
    return await _search(id_, ids, found, "task_3")


async def main(id_: str) -> None:
    found = Event()
    tasks = [
        create_task(task_1(id_, found)),
        create_task(task_2(id_, found)),
        create_task(task_3(id_, found)),
    ]
    await found.wait()
    for task in tasks:
        task.cancel()
    results = await gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    for result in results:
        if not isinstance(result, Exception):
            print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(main("230502-14191"))
```

---

### PPS: Use a `Queue` instead of an `Event`

Alternatively you can set up a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) to put the result in and simply await that result in the `main` coroutine. That may be a more elegant solution alltogether, but I suppose that is a matter of preference:

```py
from asyncio import Queue, create_task, gather, run, sleep
from collections.abc import Iterable


async def _search(id_: str, ids: Iterable[str], q: Queue, name: str) -> None:
    for i in ids:
        await sleep(0)
        print(f"{name} checking {i}")
        if i == id_:
            q.put_nowait(f"Found {id_} in {name}")


async def task_1(id_: str, q: Queue) -> None:
    ids = ["230327-12717", "230221-28276", "230214-06090"]
    await _search(id_, ids, q, "task_1")


async def task_2(id_: str, q: Queue) -> None:
    ids = ["230502-14191", "230425-17005", "230327-14434"]
    await _search(id_, ids, q, "task_2")


async def task_3(id_: str, q: Queue) -> None:
    ids = ["230404-23786", "230221-25729", "230221-28276"]
    await _search(id_, ids, q, "task_3")


async def main(id_: str) -> None:
    result_queue = Queue()
    tasks = [
        create_task(task_1(id_, result_queue)),
        create_task(task_2(id_, result_queue)),
        create_task(task_3(id_, result_queue)),
    ]
    result = await result_queue.get()
    for task in tasks:
        task.cancel()
    await gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(main("230502-14191"))
```

Awaiting `Queue.get` will block until there is an item in the queue, then return that item. So this accomplishes essentially the same as the `Event` from before, but it also gives you the result right away.

You should still clean up (i.e. cancel and await) the other tasks though.

Comment: it seems to be exactly what I am looking for at least part of it but it is not returning instead of printing let's say I want to `return f"Found {id_} in {name}"` instead of printing. How can I do that?

Comment: @X-somtheing I added two alternative solutions. One still using `gather` to collect the results returned by the tasks. The other using a `Queue`, which I think is even better in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much `Queue` one worked perfectly fine for my use case. Although I tried the `Event` solution it is giving `None` when I return the `result` instead of print. I am referring to this line `if not isinstance(result, Exception):  return result` -> `None`.